# Can I put my Wordpress theme files in another folder?

Tags: directory

Currently my folder structure looks something like

```
...\themes\MyTheme
  - \lib
  - \src
  - index.php
  - style.css
  - more theme files
  - .gitignore
  - README.md
  - many other non-Wordpress files
```

I'd like to change it into something more like

```
...\themes\MyTheme
  - \lib
  - \src
  - \wp - Pretty much all my theme's .php files
  - .gitignore
  - README.md
  - many other non-Wordpress files
```

Comment: Remember the `index.php,  functions.php and styles.css` should be in your themes directory.  Than you can change the files.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Like @Kvvaradha mentioned in his comments. If you put

```
header.php
footer.php
index.php
functions.php
style.css
```

must be in /wp-content/themes/your-theme-folder. And other your library, components and includes could be put anywhere that you prefer. But, make sure files and folders structure are flexible. Good luck in your codes :)

Comment: The question was "can I put **all** my theme files in some other directory?" and your answer is no, not yes as you write. sorry for being pedantic here.

Comment: Also, sidebar.php is mandatory (throws notice) and also comments.php etc. How do you manage these files? get_footer / get_header etc. can be replaced by get_template_part('wp_stuff/header'); so you don't have to have them in root I guess ...

Comment: @trainoasis Thanks for your point out. I just need to check again.