# Can I change get_template_directory_uri()?

Tags: directory

This is sort of a follow up to [Can I put my Wordpress theme files in another folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211632/can-i-put-my-wordpress-theme-files-in-another-folder)

I found that following

```
...\wp-content\themes\MyTheme
  - \dist
  - \lib
  - \src
  - \wp - All my Wordpress files like index.php, style.css, functions.php, etc.
  - .gitignore
  - README.md
  - many other non-Wordpress files
```

Generally works in better grouping my Wordpress files into its own folder. However, it also changes `get_template_directory_uri()` to now point to `...\themes\MyTheme\wp` which means somewhere in my `header.php` I am calling

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/../dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

I'd like for `get_template_directory_uri()` to point to `...\themes\MyTheme` so I can avoid having to use the `/../` thing in the path.

Comment: You can write a custom fucntion to pointing  your custom directory as theme uri.  And than you can make it work by using this action filter `template_directory_uri`.  Also one more suggestion I guess it similar to child theme.  So check some informations for child theme creations. Read it from official codec page.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the function [in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L319), you'll see the `template_directory_uri` hook [you can filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to modify output.

```
return apply_filters( 'template_directory_uri', $template_dir_uri, $template, $theme_root_uri );
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to contribute a more detailed answer as I found figuring out 'add_filter()' was quite frustrating.

In order to edit the hook for get_template_directory_uri(), you need to add filter as

```
add_filter('template_directory_uri', 'yourFunction', 10, 2);
```

where function is the function you are calling to edit the string, as such:

```
function yourFunction($string) {
    //Modify the string here
    return $string;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this question in the future!

Answer (score 0):

well you could probably create a variable at the start of your header.php and assign its value string as your desired path....

```
<?php $dir = your_path_here ?>
```

theoretically this should work :) best not to change wordpress stuff as it might be used somewhere else

Comment: perhaps I am just looking for a method to get to `...\themes\MyTheme`. Something besides hardcoding or using `get_template_directory_uri()` with `/../`

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for this when doing a migration to a site with another domain name. I fixed this by searching the database. These values are set in the `wp_options` table of your database. In my case, rows with `option_name` equal to `siteurl` and `home`. I updated the values and everything now works as expected.

Comment: What is wrong about this answer that it merits a downvote?